# How to Write an or statement with

Tags: java

i have tried to run it multiple ways, but the dialog box comes up even if one is selected. How do i get the dialog box to come up if only one of the buttons is not selected?

```
    if (!shapesButtons[0].isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select one of the Buttons ");
    } else if (!shapesButtons[1].isSelected()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select one of the Buttons ");
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You meant AND, not OR, because you want dialog to show "if button1 not selected *AND* button2 not selected", so you need: `if (!shapesButtons[0].isSelected() && !shapesButtons[1].isSelected())`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this rule will apply to all buttons in `shapesButtons`, you may want to go for a solution that is more maintainable (as new buttons are added in the future) such as checking the entire array:

```java
...
if (!anyButtonsSelected(shapesButtons))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select one of the Buttons ");
...

// There may be a cuter way to write this method.
private boolean anyButtonsSelected(Button[] buttons) {
    for(Button button : buttons) { // Not sure if this is the right type
         if (button.isSelected())
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to write this.  Read `||` as "or" and `&&` as "and".  Go with whichever way makes more sense to you.

Using "and":

```
if (!shapesButtons[0].isSelected() && !shapesButtons[1].isSelected()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select one of the Buttons ");
}
```

Using "or":

```
if (! (shapesButtons[0].isSelected() || shapesButtons[1].isSelected())) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select one of the Buttons ");
}
```